# how to do Timer task in java

Tags: java

I just want to implement the following in Java , Do anyone have some idea..?

```
public String method1(){

   //statement1
    .
    .
    .

   //statement 5
}
```

I want to set a timer for the statemen1 ( which involves some network communication ) . If the statement1 is not getting finished even after 25seconds , the control should go to statement 5 . how can I implement this in java ..?

Comment: What kind of network communication are you doing.  Most java network classes allow you to set a timeout, so it will do it for you automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `java.util.TimerTask`.

extend `TimerTask` and over-ride the `run()` method.

What you put in the run method is what should be executed every *25* seconds.

To start the timer do the following:

`Timer tmer = new Timer("Network Timer",false);`

`ExtendedTimerTask extdTT = new ExtendedTimerTask(<params_go_here>)`
`tmer.schedule(extdTT,25000,25000);`

You can parse the object which does the networking part at `<params_go_here>` and assign to a local variable in your `ExtendedTimerTask`.

When the timer executes you can do the necassary calls on your `<params_go_here>` object to see if its finished.

Please note that the checker will run in a seperate thread as `java.util.TimerTask` implements `java.util.Runnable`

Cool

Comment: The reason I am using the TimerTask is because it is very similar in behaviour in comparison with a .Net Timer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
private volatile Object resultFromNetworkConnection;    

public String method1(){
   resultFromNetworkConnection = null;
   new Thread(){
       public void run(){
           //statement1
           .
           .
           .
           // assign to result if the connection succeeds
       }
   }.start();
   long start = System.currentMilis();
   while (System.currentMilis() - start < 25 * 1000) {
       if (resultFromNetworkConnection != null) break;
       Thread.sleep(100);
   }
   // If result is not null, you can use it, otherwise, you can ignore it
   //statement 5
}
```

Comment: I suppose you would want to make resultFromNetworkConnection volatile as well.

Comment: @aioobe, well, if you end up doing it this way, yeah.

Comment: @aioobe, You may like the updated version better.  You don't have to wait 25 seconds no matter what!

Comment: no, the two threads may still cache their own versions of `resultFromNetworkConnection`. You need to put `volatile` in front of `Object resultFrom...` (or introduce some other synchronization mechanism).

Comment: @aioobe, ok, I see your point.  You cannot make a local volatile though, so it has to be a member.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no time-out parameter for the blocking method at statement1, you would have to put statement1 in a separate thread, then `wait(25000)` for it to finish, if the `wait` times-out, you go ahead with statement 5 and ignore the result of the blocking call.

Answer (score 0):

I/O operations (including network communication) are synchronous. So you can configure a timeout for the particular network communication, and you will have the desired behaviour. How exactly to configure the timeout - depends on what you are using.

Comment: *"you can configure a timeout"*, well this depends on what API he's using I suppose.

Comment: that's exactly what I said ;)

Comment: I'm saying, whether or not you *can* configure the time-out at all depends on the API, right?

Comment: @aioobe, yeah, some libraries may not offer a timeout property.

Answer (score 0):

You mention network communication, so I'll give a rough example with an InputStream from a Socket with a timeout set that may apply to other classes.  While you could make timer threads, this is simpler.

```
socket.setSoTimeout(25 * 1000);

try
{
    data = readMyData(socket.getInputStream());
    doStuff(data);
}
catch(SocketTimeoutException e){ }

doStatement5();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a pattern that you can use. The idea is to start a separate thread to do the network stuff. The "main" thread will wait for the adequate time and check a shared variable that indicates if the networking stuff did his job on time.

```
public class TestConstrainNetworkOP {

    private Object lock = new Object();
    private Object dataAvailable;

    private Object constrainedNetworkOp() throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t = new Thread(new DoTask());
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(25000);
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (dataAvailable != null) {
                //the data arrived on time
            }
            else{
                //data is not available and 
                            //maybe throw a timeoutexception
            }
        }
    }

    public class DoTask implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // do the networking
            synchronized (lock) {
                // save your data here
                dataAvailable = new Long(1);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is a useful pattern if you don't too much control over the network layer (e.g. RMI, EJB). If you are writing the network communication by yourself, then you can set the timeout direct to the socket (as people previously said) or use [Java NIO](http://books.google.com/books?id=BSz14O3uQwsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=java+nio&source=bl&ots=ZOQ4d6ExcD&sig=X2JsPUCNGRauQkf52Ag3J0f4xBk&hl=en&ei=W11-TNzWCYT58Abm9-TTAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q&f=false)