# How to set up a timer for two min in Java

Tags: java, timer

How would I set up a timer in java that prints out "Times up" after two minutes have passed? Javascript has a setTimeout function, but does Java have anything similar to that?

Comment: Have you looked into the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/)? I can see three `Timer` classes, `java.util.Timer`, `javax.swing.Timer` and `javax.management.timer.Timer`.  You could also achieve the same thing using a `Thread` and `Thread.sleep`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to do Timer task in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618653/how-to-do-timer-task-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Timer` to [`schedule(TimerTask, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-long-); and you could use [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) to calculate your delay. Something like,

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Times up");
    }
};
long delay = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(2);
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(task, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Swing then do not use `Thread.sleep()` as it will freeze your Swing application.

Instead you should use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

See the Java tutorial [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java's `Thread.sleep()`. Its parameter is also in milliseconds.

Try this:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(120000);
} catch(InterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

The `catch` is necessary in Java in the case of an early breaking out of the "sleep", though: in JS, the `setTimeout()` runs in the background, but in Java it is the main process.

You can see [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html) from Oracle's Java tutorials. Note that they `throw InterruptedException` instead of catching it.